# Python3 PiCamera Module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, camera, picamera

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a Camera (Noir) and I found on python this pi camera module. So I have now when I am starting the python script a Webserver which allows me to see throw my camera. Thats fine and cool, but now I wanted to make with some php and html a form with two buttons:

1. Start Video, actually starts video to record somewhere at /home/pi/x
2. Stop Video , which actually stops only the recording and not the whole stream.

Heres my code

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
         //code to be executed
        shell_exec("./start_video.sh");
    }else{
         //code to be executed
    }
   if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
       shell_exec("./stop_video.sh");
   }else{

   }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</title>
</head>
<body>

<center><h1>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="1280" height="720"></center>

<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Video">
       <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Stop Video">     
</form>

</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
         try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='1280x720', framerate=30) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    #Uncomment the next line to change your Pi's Camera rotation (in degrees)
    #camera.rotation = 90
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) to setup the server instead of a basic HTTPServer with php.
Using shell scripts that get called via php and control stuff inside the server is not very elegant and might not even work.

[This Hackster project](https://www.hackster.io/ruchir1674/video-streaming-on-flask-server-using-rpi-ef3d75#toc-4--program-4) might be a good starting point for streaming with flask. To start/stop the video, one (crude) possibility could be to have a variable that gets toggled inside `start_video` and `stop_video` routes and controls whether the video feed returns an image or not.

In order to record video at the same time as streaming it through the webserver, [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/record-and-stream-video-from-camera-simultaneously) might be useful.

Comment: So you suggest I need to use flask to setup the server? well alright I can easily change that. But the error will be same, if I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I suggested Flask because with that you could ditch php plus the `start_video.sh` and `stop_video.sh` scripts in favor of controlling the picamera-API from within python.